# How do I access this variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

For the following code:

```
export var enableTraps = false;

/**
 * Drops into the debugger.
 * @param breakIfTrue if undefined or true, will break.
 */
export var trap = function (breakIfTrue?: boolean): void {
    if (!enableTraps)
        return;
    if ((breakIfTrue === undefined) || breakIfTrue)
        debugger;
}
```

The debugger tells me that enableTraps in the trap function is undefined. How do I specify the var enableTraps?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The debugger tells me that enableTraps in the trap function is undefined. How do I specify the var enableTraps

What you have is correct TS/JS. I don't believe you. Unless you have found a bug in the *runtime environment you are working with*.

Comment: You're right - the IE debugger was not properly displaying the value.

Comment: FWIW `I don't believe you` was meant as a joke :)

Comment: Oh yes, I did take it as a joke. But it also did make me look again. So funny and solved my problem.